# Reading Multiple Files in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I cant seem to find a solution to this problem.

I use pandas to read my first excel file and extract the information. I then use the information to update a new excel file which in turn updates the formulas.

I want to use pandas again to read the new file but it is still reading the original file. I used `filename.close()` to close the first file but it still remembers everything from that file. It wont read the second file.

This is reading the first file

```
firstDate = []
dateHeader = []
dataList = []`

xl = pandas.ExcelFile(xlsx)
sheets = xl.sheet_names
df = xl.parse(sheets[2])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    dateStamp = row[2].date()
    creationMonth = dateStamp.month
    creationDay = dateStamp.day
    creationYear = dateStamp.year
    creationDate = datetime.date(creationYear, creationMonth, 1)
    endDate = datetime.datetime.now()
    #Create a list to hold all the dates
    dateList = []
    #Iterate through the different dates
    for i, dt in enumerate(rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=creationDate, until=endDate)):
        #Format the date into the correct format
        date = dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        #Create a condition to skip of the present date
        if i > 0:
           #Append the date to the dateList
           dateList.append(date)
    #Get the length of the date list
    lenLst = len(dateList)
    #Create the date range list
    dateRangeList = []
    #Iterate through the date list
    for i, value in enumerate(dateList):
        #Create a check to not fo beyond the bounds of the list
        if i != (lenLst - 1):
            #Get the start date
            sRange = dateList[i]
            #Get the end date
            eRange = dateList[i + 1]
            #Set the date range
            dateRange = [sRange, eRange]
            #Append the rnage to the date range list
            dateRangeList.append(dateRange)
    if dateStamp not in firstDate:
        firstDate.append(dateStamp)
    baseData = [row[0], '%s/%s/%s' %(creationMonth, creationDay, creationYear), row[3], dateRangeList]
    dataList.append(baseData)
xl.close()
```

This reads the second file

```
for i, value in enumerate(dataList):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx)
    worksheets = wb.sheetnames
    worksheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(worksheets[0])
    rowCoordinate = i
    meterName = value[0]
    creationDate = value[1]
    units = value[2]
    worksheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = meterName
    wb.save(copyXlsx)
    dateList = []
    for k, dateRange in enumerate(value[3]):
        sDate = dateRange[0]
        eDate = dateRange[1]
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(copyXlsx)
        worksheets = wb.sheetnames
        worksheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(worksheets[0])
        worksheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value = sDate
        worksheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value = eDate
        wb.save(copyXlsx1)
        print meterName, dateRange
        xl1 = pandas.ExcelFile(copyXlsx1)
        sheets1 = xl1.sheet_names
        df = xl1.parse(sheets1[0])
        print df
```

Comment: Can you please post the code

Comment: @NickHale I have posted the code

Comment: doesn't `pandas.ExcelFile` have a `context manager`? And if you have 2 excel files, why give them the same name `xlsx`

Comment: @MaartenFabré The excel files have different names. The first one has the variable name xlsx and the second one is xlsxCopy there is also an xlsxCopy1

Comment: then what do you mean with `I want to use pandas again to read the new file but it is still reading the original file. I used filename.close() to close the first file but it still remembers everything from that file. It wont read the second file.`

Comment: @maarten pandas is remembering the information from the first file it seems. I go to the new excel file and it's been updates but when I view the second data frame in pandas the data doesn't match. It matches the first file. I am unsure why it's doing that.

Comment: pandas only opens the file when reading, so if something else adjusts it, you'll have to reread it again

Comment: @MaartenFabre that makes sense I thought I did that by closing the original file and opening a new one. Did I do it incorrectly?